# rqworker from django-rq not receiving tasks

Tags: python, django, django-rq

I am trying to have some asynchronous functions run by a worker following the approach explained [here](http://blog.ashnab.com/task-queues-and-python-rq/).

That means, in my `tasks.py` file I have:

```
from django_rq import job
@job
def long_function(one_list):

    #many stuff that should be done asynchrounously
```

Then in my `views.py` file:

```
from .tasks import long_function
def render_function(request):
    #some code to get one_list

    long_function.delay(one_list)

    #some more code to render the page

    return render(request, 'results_page.html', context)
```

For the moment I am doing the tests locally.
Therefore, I have two Terminals opened: one to run `python manage.py runserver` and another to run `python manage.py rqworker default`.

So when I load 'results_page.html' in the browser I expect that the tasks are queued and start running with the rqworker. The problem is that this happens only some random times, while in the rest the Terminal for rqworker just shows:

```
*** Listening on default...
Sent heartbeat to prevent worker timeout. Next one should arrive within 420 seconds.
Sent heartbeat to prevent worker timeout. Next one should arrive within 420 seconds.
```

My first idea was that as I am using two different terminals simultaneously, the connection was not properly done. However, I think this does not make sense because sometimes the asynchronous task does run.

Why is the worker not seeing the tasks sometimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this](https://www.imagescape.com/blog/2013/06/13/simple-job-queues-django_rq/) article, I replaced the `delay` function in `views.py`.

From

```
from .tasks import long_function

def render_function(request):
    #some code to get one_list

    long_function.delay(one_list)

    #some more code to render the page

    return render(request, 'results_page.html', context)
```

to

```
import django_rq
from .tasks import long_function

def render_function(request):
    #some code to get one_list

    queue = django_rq.get_queue('default')
    queue.enqueue(long_function, one_list)

    #some more code to render the page

    return render(request, 'results_page.html', context)
```

And it seems to be working. No idea why, though...

Comment: It could be related to this: https://github.com/ui/django-rq/issues/193